# Template Metaprogramming NamedPipe Client Server

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I am writing a NamedPipe extraction for C++11 and would like to have the following API*:

```
template<typename Mode>
class NamedPipe final {
    public:
        void Open();

        std::enable_if<Mode == Receiver>
        void Send();

        std::enable_if<Mode == Receiver>
        void Receive();

        void Close();
}
```

So that use looks like so:

```
NamedPipe<Sender> pipe_sender("test");
NamedPipe<Reciever> pipe_receiver("test");
pipe_sender.Open();
pipe_receiver.Open();
pipe_sender.Send("Some data");
pipe_receiver.Receive();
pipe_sender.Receive(); <--- compilation error
```

I have been using the `type_traits` in C++11 but only really just got into them - I've really enjoyed using them but this is really flexing the learning curve.  Is there anyone with enough knowledge to point me in the right direction?

* the first example is deliberately rough as I keep going around in circles with the template stuff - I really just need to be put on the right path!

Comment: While I don't think enable_if is appropriate here, I wrote something about [using enable_if in C++11](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html) on my blog that you may or may not find interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force compilation errors easily with static assertions:

```
template<typename Mode>
class NamedPipe final {
    public:
        void Open();    
        void Send();    
        void Receive();    
        void Close();
}        
template<typename Mode>
void NamedPipe<Mode>::Send() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Mode, Sender>::value, "Cannot send from receivers");
    // blah blah implementation
}        
template<typename Mode>
void NamedPipe<Mode>::Receive() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Mode, Receiver>::value, "Cannot receive with senders");
    // blah blah implementation
}
```

This not only gives compilation errors, but it gives nice descriptive errors.